# SelectField WTforms not valid choice and sa_instance_state

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm encountering a number of errors when implementing a WTForms SelectField in an application built with Flask/SQLalchemy.

Here's the relevant code:

**Views.py:**

```
form = ReviewForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        review = Review(rating=form.rating.data, body=form.body.data, pub_date=datetime.utcnow(), author=g.user, item=thing)
        db.session.add(review)
        db.session.commit()
```

**Models.py**

```
RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 4),
        (5, 5),
    )

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class ReviewForm(Form):
    rating = SelectField('rating', choices=Review.RATING_CHOICES, validators=[Required()])
    body = TextAreaField('body', validators=[Required()])
    tags = StringField('tags', validators=[Required()])
```

So right now, with code as it is...I'm getting a "Not a valid choice" issue.  I'm assuming it's interpreting my rating as a string or tuple or something and as a result, it isn't feeding properly to `rating=db.column(db.Integer)`.

However, upon adding coerce=int to the selectfield arguments, I start encountering:

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

File "", line 194, in blank
review = Review(rating=form.rating.data, body=form.body.data, pub_date=datetime.utcnow(), author=g.user, item=thing)
File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
```

I'm clearly missing something here or sending something wrong...I'm just not savvy enough to dig into what the form is returning and figure it out.

Comment: Just a note that I've already tried coerce=int and got the attribute error above.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can always print **from.data** to see what data is being sent back for rating.

Now about you second error *_sa_instance_state*. Looks like it is being caused by your **g.user**. If this user is already present in the database sqlalchemy will just set the foreign key. If it is a new/anonymous user object, it will try to save user along with your Review.

Is your user of type *AnonymousUserMixin* ? If yes, are you missing **db.Model** in user's inheritance ?

Comment: Sorry for responding so late!  You're correct.  The reason I was getting the error was because I wasn't a logged in user within my instance and I hadn't build an exception rule for that!  Dumb I know, but posting this to help someone else out if they forget haha.